# Displaying image stored as binary in Postgresql bytea column with pgAdmin

Tags: image, postgresql, base64, pgadmin

I converted an image to a base64 string and then insert it directly into the table with pgAdmin, and now I am wondering how I can retrieve the image back?

Is it possible to just do it with pdAdmin or would I need to execute it with C or Java code?